# SDK error configuration env in tensorflow certificate

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

i have error before taking exam, here :

```
Cannot set up a python SDK at Python (TensorFlow) (C:\Users\ryan\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.2\certification\venv\Scripts\python.exe). The SDK seems invalid.
```

the error says invalid sdk, anyone know about problem please advice me